# Add shortcut to custom settings

Tags: apex, customsetting

Is there a way to create a shortcut or quick access button to custom settings in salesforce? I want sales team to easily add new values or remove existing without going into setup, but custom object seems too heavy since I will store key - value pairs, so it's just name + field with lookup relationship.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to create a visualforce page that would expose the custom settings in a user-friendly way. This way you wouldn't need to grant their profiles the permission required to access that section of the setup.